# Google glass- unable to get address from location

Tags: android, geolocation, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to get address of a location by passing latitude and longitude.But the address is always null.

Here is my code..

```
@Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        if (location != null){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Start_service.this.getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        // lat,lng, your current location

        try {
            lati= location.getLatitude();
            longi=location.getLongitude();
            speed=location.getSpeed();
            addresses =geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(), 1);
        System.out.println("Address is"+ addresses);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Android's `Geocoder` doc:

> The `Geocoder` class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The `Geocoder` query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the `isPresent()` method to determine whether a `Geocoder` implementation exists.

If you would like to have it supported on Glass, feel free to file a feature request on our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

You could also use alternative API such as the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Comment: It works when I tether it to a phone with GPS.It doesnt work with wi-fi